# React-Native require a class from a 'non-class' .js and use the functions

Tags: class, controller, react-native, require

I want to "outsource" my logical functions which I need over more than 3-4 classes. Therefore I created a .js file and entered the functions. But I did not create a class for it. Instead I am using the following syntax:

```
var myMainClassWithTheFunction = require('./myMain...');

var FunctionHandler = {
    myFunction(){
        myMainClassWiththeFunction.testFunction();            
    }
}

module.exports = FunctionHandler
```

Inside of this function I want to use the method of another class -> The class is structured like the following

```
class MyMainClass.. extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
static testFunction(
    alert("Test");
)
render(){...}
}

module.exports = MyMainClass;
```

**The class MyMainClass... is working (Checked through many other calls - But those just got from other classes)**

I also tested `myFunction` from `FunctionHandler` with a function testAlert() which worked perfectly.

**The main issue**
As far as I try to call the `testFunction()` from the MainClass I get the following error:

> *undefined is not a function(evaluating 'myMainClass.testFunction()'*

- I tried a static/non-static function

**My question**
How can I solve this problem - or do you even know better ways to *outsource* the logical behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of searching what my issue is here i found out that:

> If you fill your `js-file` with just a `var` like i did. You cannot require other `classes` in another `var` and use the `var` in other `var's` (in my case my FunctionHandler `var`)

**Solution**

> I required the classes inside my var so i could use them.

```
var FunctionHandler = {
    var myMainClassWithTheFunction = require('./myMain...');

    myFunction(){
        myMainClassWiththeFunction.testFunction();            
    }
}
```

module.exports = FunctionHandler

*I am sure many people now roll their eyes if they read this and think 'this is clear' but for me it was a timeintensive issue. Hopefully anyone can help this*

Answer (score 0):

You are exporting the class `ListViewMain` instead of `MyMainClass`. I assume you have multiple classes in the same file: `ListViewMain` and `MyMainClass`. Either move `MyMainClass` to a separate file and export `MyMainClass` or change your export to something like:

```
module.exports = {ListViewMain, MyMainClass};
```

To use it

```
var {MyMainClass} = require('./myMainClass');
```

Alternatively you could use ES6 Syntax:

```
export class MyMainClass extends Component {...}
```

To use it

```
import {MyMainClass} from './myMainClass';
```

Comment: Hey Daniel, sry for the late response. I just have the right syntax in my code with the module.exports - just for the short example i made it wrong. Sry for that so far i still edited the questin. But you solutions with {] around the var and the ES6 syntax are not working. As far as i have a solution for this i let you know.

Comment: I added the reason for my issue as an answer if you are interested in :) thanks anyway for your help.